# How to access each key and value of json in JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have stored some data as a JSON. Data is coming dynamically. Even the key name could be changed.

```
var str = {
  "Product_row_1": {
    "Number_of_Students": {
      190: 191
    },
    "Price": {
      240.0000: 230.0000
    },
    "Total_Old": {
      "45.00000": "43.00000"
    }
  },
  "Cost": {
    45.00: 43.00
  },
  "Cost_after": {
    45.00: 43.00
  },
  "Total": {
    45.00: 43.00
  },
  "Cover_Letter": {
    "<div>Hello<\/div>": ""
  },
  "Additional_Information": {
    "<div>Hell No<\/div>": ""
  }
}
```

Now I want to access it's all keys and values.
I'm trying JSON.parse() but it's giving error "Unexpected number in JSON at position 40".
I tried this with  $.getJSON(Json, function (key, value).That's also not working.

Can someone please help ?
I just want to access each key, value and inside JSON ( {"Product_row_1":{"aa":"bb"}} ) as well.

Comment: To parse JSON you need to supply valid JSON. Numeric property names are not valid.

Comment: `Object.keys(str)` and `Object.values(str)` please note `str` is not actually a string, it's an object

Comment: `"Cost": {
    45.00: 43.00
  },` does not make any sense either

Comment: Thanks I got that,
I'll convert these into string.
Can you please tell me the way to access these all dynamic keys and values through loop or something else ?